# Undefined error when executing command to list PhoneGap plugins (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We're on PhoneGap 3.2, but the command to list plugins is generating an error:

```
w prompt$ phonegap local plugin list
[error] undefined
```

We're building for iOS. We have successfully installed several plugins, which are verified by looking at the plugins folder.

Did the command syntax change in 3.2, or is this a bug?

Comment: I am also getting this as well since going to 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue that has just recently been fixed (About an hour from the posting of this answer).

[Google Groups Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/eccZhqxW0ZA)

To correct it just do the following

```
 $ npm install -g phonegap
```